# What does "emphasizer vs. adjunct" mean?

Tags: meaning

"I do not really get to do much topical material."

A scholarly  paper gives that sentence, and it then comments: "Really" performs the function of emphasizer vs. adjunct.

What does it  mean by "emphasizer vs. adjunct"?

Thank you

Comment: The context should be able to answer that.

Comment: [Adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_%28grammar%29); *emphasizer* -- something which emphasises. The phrase means "[functions as] something which emphasises rather than as a disposable adjunct".

Answer (score 1):

> "I do not really get to do much topical material."

In this sentence, really, isn't necessary. However, it *emphasizes* that you don't get do much topical material.

As Andrew Leach had ***[linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_%28grammar%29)*** in his comment:

> an **adjunct** is an optional, or structurally dispensable, part of a sentence, clause, or phrase that, when removed, will not affect the remainder of the sentence

So...

> "I do not get to do much topical material"

The sentence is fine without 'really'.

The phrase ***emphasizer vs adjunct***, going off assumption, is that the sentence contains both, an emphasis and an adjunct. And ***depending on the rest of context that you did not give***, the "scholarly" paper may have been arguing what kind of sentence that was; regardless of all of that, I'd have to also agree with Kris that the context should be able to answer that.